# Ubuntu Server installation on SSHD

Tags: sshd

Is it a good procedure to install Ubuntu Server 14.10 on an SSHD (8 GB SSD + 2 TB HDD)? 
Or perhaps it is better to install the OS on an SSD and mount an HDD for data storage?

Comment: Question really doesn't make sense.  If you have an SSD an an HDD, then install on those.  If you have a single SSHD, then install on that.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should better install **/** (root) on your ssd, and all other stuff (home, etc.) on your hdd.

Works great for me in that way.

Comment: Yes, I will do that way

Comment: The question is about an SSHD not an SSD + an HDD

Answer (score 0):

The whole reason of having an SSD is because you want the content that is accessed a lot to be the fastest.

So if you have a lot of things you access in your /etc directory then that should be on the SSD.

You also have the option of using a RAM disk for items that require speed.

Ultimately it is up to you and your usage case.

For a standard web server the best thing to put on the SSD would depend on how large the SSD is and how much time you want to spend on it and if you need to repeat this process more then once.

--------UPDATE------------
In this instance you are working with a limited about of space and it will depend on what additional modules you install.  I would just look at what runs the most and then type "which" command to find out where the most used services are located.  After that I would check the size requirements out of my top 5 most used programs and then figure out future growth and see if it makes sense to put those services on the SSD or not.  I would think MySQL and PHP are going to be some important pieces along with your main application folder.

If it is just a home server then I would honestly just install everything on the 2TB HDD and then use the SSD on things I know I would like to have as fast as possible.

It is relatively easy to move a directory to a new partition if you find out you would like some additional speed when you find out your usage patterns.

Comment: Lets say I want to install Ubuntu Server 14.10 together with GlobalSight (TMS) and ISPconfig. The SSD has 500 GB, the HDD eventually more or less. The data files of Globalsight will be preferably installed in the HDD, together with all the website files of the WebServer and eventually also the files of the MailServer. The point is, for me, Ubuntu is much confusing as Windows...  : )

Comment: In this instance you are working with a limited about of space and it will depend on what additional modules you install.  I would just look at what runs the most and then type "which" command to find out where the most used services are located.  After that I would check the size requirements out of my top 5 most used programs and then figure out future growth and see if it makes sense to put those services on the SSD or not.  I would think MySQL and PHP are going to be some important pieces along with your main application folder.

Comment: I mean, the services (Apache, MySQL and PHP) are supposed to be installed on the SSD, only the database(s) should be saved on the HDD, like all the work files and website files (.php, html, etc.)

Comment: Ideally you would want the MySQL files on the SSD if it was large enough.  You would also want the PHP files along with the interpreter as well.  I have no idea as to the size your MySQL server files will grow to.  It might not end up being a problem for you for quite some time.  Like I said it is extremely easy to move a partition later.

Comment: That is, in this case I should use at the beginning only the 500 GB SSD and, if things grow fast, I can always change everything into a bigger SSD or move partitions into other mounted HDD (?)

Comment: Yeah it is as easy as editing an fstab file and copying over the data.  Check this link - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  They talk about the home directory, but it gives you an example of the process.